# Add JavaScript with $doc->addScript with async="true"

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, jdocument

is it possible to use the `addScript` with `async="true"`?

I found a hack that uses some clever quoting to trick the embed function, but it seems as if this could be a native feature:

```
$doc->addScript("//myscript.js", 'text/javascript" async="true');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a look at the Joomla `addScript` function, it shows the following:

```
public function addScript($url, $type = "text/javascript", $defer = false, $async = false)
{
    $this->_scripts[$url]['mime'] = $type;
    $this->_scripts[$url]['defer'] = $defer;
    $this->_scripts[$url]['async'] = $async;

    return $this;
}
```

`$async` is a boolean therefore the following should work for you:

```
$doc->addScript('//myscript.js', 'text/javascript', false, true);
```

The `false` is for `$defer` and `true` is for `$async`

Comment: - sorry just mistyped